# Count elements in array of arrays equal to specified value

Tags: c#, linq, enumerable

I have array of arrays. Suppose I want to count how much elements out of all 9 is equal to `"a"`.

```
string[][] arr = new string[3][] {
    new string[]{"a","b","c"},
    new string[]{"d","a","f"},
    new string[]{"g","a","a"}
};
```

How can I do it using Enumerable extension methods (`Count`, `Where`, etc)?

Comment: `.SelectMany(a => a).Count(a => a == "a")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need a way to iterate over the *subelements* of the matrix, you can do this using [**`SelectMany()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx), and then use [**`Count()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int count = arr.SelectMany(x => x).Count(x => x == "a");
```

Producing:

```
csharp> arr.SelectMany(x => x).Count(x => x == "a");
4
```

Or you could [**`Sum()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535184(v=vs.110).aspx) up the counts of the [**`Count()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181(v=vs.110).aspx)s of each individual row, like:

```
int count = arr.Sum(x => x.Count(y => y == "a"));
```

Producing again:

```
csharp> arr.Sum(x => x.Count(y => y == "a"));
4
```

Answer (score 3):

You can flatten all arrays into single sequence of strings with [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) and then use [`Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181(v=vs.110).aspx) extension which accepts predicate:

```
arr.SelectMany(a => a).Count(s => s == "a")
```